# Is there a default http request header to identify the user making a request?

Tags: http, rest, http-headers

In the data model behind my RESTful API there are several entities with the CreatedBy/ModifiedBy fields.  The only access to this data is through my API, and as such, the fields should be populated with the user id of the user making the request to my API.

I have considered either adding these fields to the models exposed by my API or expecting a request header containing the user id on all PUT/POST/DELETE requests.  I would be interested in any opinions as to which approach is best, or any other approach.

I like the idea of providing it in the header since it is necessary for every request and I am wondering if there is a standard request header to contain the information, or a common x-header.

I have seen the from request header; however, it seems to be defined as the email address of the user making the request and I need to pass the user id.

In our current implementation, we use the authorization header to authenticate the calling application with the API, and not for a specific user.

Which header would you use to pass information to identify the user making a request?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Authorization header to add your own parameters. Both the Digest and OAuth authorization schemes support parameters. The Basic scheme already have the user credentials readable. Something like:

```
 Authorization: OAuth realm="Photos",
    oauth_consumer_key="dpf43f3p2l4k3l03",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp="137131200",
    oauth_nonce="wIjqoS",
    oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fprinter.example.com%2Fready",
    oauth_signature="74KNZJeDHnMBp0EMJ9ZHt%2FXKycU%3D",
    xoauth_user_guid="alganet"
```

Yahoo! does something similar with their OAuth implementation, but in another context.

http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-accesstoken.html.

However, if these fields are shown or exposed somehow in your public API, they belong to RESTful resources and should be represented always in the body, not the headers. If you GET the username in the message body, you should POST the username using the message body as well.

Comment: The CreatedBy/ModifiedBy are just auditing fields that are used when manual checking data; they are never returned through the service.  It isn't really part of the authorization either.  Applications are authorized to use the api, not individual users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use HttpClient

```
  HttpClient client = HttpClientManager.getNewClient();
  HttpMethod get = new GetMethod(...);
  get.addRequestHeader("x-newHeader", "value");
```

more [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html)

OR using URLConnection using [setRequestParameter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: how about REST request interceptors ?

Comment: I know how to add a custom header, I was just wondering if there is a standard header that is used for something like this.